# Find the absolute maxmium of the function $f(x) = x \cdot {e}^{-x}$

Tags: calculus, functions, exponentiation, graphing-functions

How can I find the absolute maximum of this exponential function?

> $f(x) = x \cdot {e}^{-x}$

[image]

I know that the first step is to take the derivative of the function, like so:

> ${f}^{\prime}(x) = x \cdot {e}^{-x}(-1) + {e}^{-x}(1)$
>
> ${f}^{\prime}(x) = {e}^{-x}(1 - x)$

Then the next step is to set it equal to zero and find the critical points for the first derivative test. How can I do that with an exponential function?

Could someone please show how they have done that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$e^{-x}$ is never 0; but that's good here, because you can "throw it away":
$$
e^{-x}(1-x)=0\iff 1-x=0\iff x=1.
$$

(A product is 0 if and only if one of the factors is 0; so, since $e^{-x}$ is never 0, the first equation above holds if and only if the second one does. Alternatively, dividing both sides of the first equation above by $e^{-x}$ is justified.)

Comment: ohhhh... You divide through by ${e}^{-x}$. Can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you! Points up and answer accepted!

Comment: And remember: What makes it possible to "divide through" by it is that the exponential function is NEVER ZERO.  Remember that fact.